# create addition program like package

Tags: python, math, package

like this following example how can I do addition program.

## mammal.py

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Constructor for this class. '''
        # Create some member animals
        self.members = ['Tiger', 'Elephant', 'Wild Cat']
  
  
    def printMembers(self):
        print('Printing members of the Mammals class')
        for member in self.members:
            print('\t%s ' % member)
```

## test.py

```
from Animals import Mammals
from Animals import Birds
  
 
myMammal = Mammals()
myMammal.printMembers()
```

like this, I want to create addition program.I wrote following program for addition but I want to put 2 addition numbers in test.py.

## addition

```
class addition:
    def add():
        a=int(input("Enter the number : "))
        b=int(input("Enter the number two : "))
        c= a + b
        print(c)
 
obj = addition.add()
```

what I need to type in the test file.

Comment: What do you mean by: but i want to put 2 addition numbers in test.py

Comment: instead of adding two numbers in shell when you type  a=int(input.... )) code i want to add those numbers in test.py file   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain of exactly what you want, but I'm guessing that you want a program that uses your addition class, right?

It should look something like this:

**addition.py**

```
class Addition:
 def add():
    a=int(input("Enter the number : "))
    b=int(input("Enter the number two : "))
    c= a + b
    print(c)
```

**test.py**

```
from addition import Addition
operation1 = Addition.add()
>> 1
>> 2
>> 3
operation2 = Addition.add()
>> 2
>> 3
>> 5
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add them in test.py directly, and dont ask for them on shell, you should pass the numbers as parameters to your class method, so do as follows:

**addition.py**

```
class Addition:
def add(a, b):
 return a + b
```

**test.py**

```
from addition import Addition
result1 = Addition.add(3,5)
print(result1)
result2 = Addition.add(10,5)
print(result2)
```

In the code above, the method return a number and stores it on the variables "results" so in order to print it you must print the content of the variables, because the print is no longer executed at the add() method.

Comment: TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, check copy again the "class Addtion" .

Comment: but is there any way that if i want to add two numbers for addition in test.py instead of shell ?

Comment: you mean like: add(4,5) and it prints 9?

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: Please feel free to mark my response as the answer.